# Switching from Eclipse to Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to switch from Eclipse to Netbeans for my PHP projects. All is well and fine, but there are a few features that I'm missing, namely:

- Shortcut for Open method/function and go to declaration from any file in the project
- Shortcut for Display class methods for a class I'm currently in

If there are key bindings for the above, I would be happy to find them out.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shortcut for Open method/function and go to declaration from any file
>   in the project

Go To Symbol - <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Navigation in NetBeans:
http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/code_navigation

Class view provides Navigator in NetBeans - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

Comment: isn't as nice as Eclipse's but I guess it does the job

Answer (score 1):

In the last two months, I've been switching from Eclipse to Netbeans too.

- For the Open Method, you can select on the method/variable usage and then right click to get Navigate -> Go To Declaration or select and then go to the menu option Navigate -> Go To Declaration.
- For the class information, you want the Navigator. In the Menu, go to Window -> Navigating -> Navigator.

If you have any questions, feel free to drop me a note. There are about 10-12 of us in the core PHP community that are switching.